Subgroup toggle in qgis2web
When you export a map to a webmap through qgis2web, you have a checkbox in the legends to toggle on/off each layer. However, I have a categorized symbology and I want to be able to put checkboxes on each category so that only one or two category of that layer is visible. Is this possible?

It is not supported by qgis2web.  The only way is to duplicate the layer and delete the symbologies you don't want to export.

I want the layers to be exported, but I need to have a checkbox that can toggle them on/off. As it is it only toggles as a whole layer. I want each individual category to be toggleable. TomazicM can you provide me with the code for this?

You can export your map with leaflet and set filters in the Appearance tab.

The result is a map in which it is possible to turn the layer on and off completely and act on the filter to view only the desired data on the map.
Webmap without filter:

Webmap with filter:

